# Rule Fudging for Large Groups

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques

I'm running a 3.5 campaign for a large group (8 players, I must be crazy), none of which have every played before, and several of which are quite young (ages 13-17).  I've got some ideas for changing up the set up to make it flow faster (mentioning who is "on deck," etc.), but I was wondering if there were any good rule changes / adjustments for 3.5 that would speed up combat and just generally make the game flow faster.

Comment: Lots. Most of them are likely mutually exclusive, or redundant, or entirely unneeded at your table, or actively unhelpful, or intended to promote styles you're not necessarily looking for, or otherwise not useful. You're going to need to elaborate on what you need, I think.

Comment: Also I would like to add that the game don't really get that slow until you start using dozen of spellcasting items (wands, scrolls, etc), someone in the party is specialized in summon magic (able to double or triple the party numbers), or the players earn multiple attacks per round (level 6+). For new players starting at level 1, none of those are a big concern for a while.

Comment: I have an answer for this question that might not apply to the other one, since it focuses more on the players being new and might not actually be helpful for more experienced players who are just prone to taking forever. What are the protocols for that?